# encoding of period in text output

Tags: bash, character-encoding, xdotool

I am trying to output this `xdotool type '172.06'` into a textbox, but it enters `17206.` Is there something wrong with the encoding? Why would it enter the period last? Note that when I run this in terminal it works perfectly.

I found a [google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xdotool-users/ySNlZ6rp0Us) about the topic, but didnt see an answer that applied to the `.` symbol

Notes:

xdotool version 3.20150503.1

layout:     us

xdotool works in terminal (linux mint)

textbox is a text input field in the game EVE (not sure how to give more info about this)

Comment: What version of `xdotool` do you have (post output of `xdotool --version`)? What exactly is a `textbox`? What keyboard layout do you use (show output of `setxkbmap -query | grep layout`)? Does `xdotool` work correctly in a terminal? It works nice for me inside `xterm` and `Xdialog` input box. I have `xdotool version 3.20160801.1`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment- those were details I needed to post, but had no idea how to get!

Comment: You said that `xdotool` works *correctly* inside terminal  - does it mean it outputs `172.06` as intended instead of `17206.` as it happens inside `EVE` window?  If that's the case, what happens when you manually type `172.06` inside `EVE`? You may have luck with `--delay` option, for example: `xdotool type --delay 1000 '172.06'` - observe input box inside `EVE` and learn when `.` is moved out of its place.

Comment: My foremost speculation would have to do with EVE doing something on its side; you want to [edit] your question to show how this is not the case if you want this to be investigated properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you run

```
xdotool type '172' && xdotool type '.' && xdotool type '06'
```

? if it works, try to increase the typing delay

```
xdotool type --delay 25 '172.06'
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `;` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Same same in this case. Unless the operation fails, it will run as a sequence of commands anyhow.